# Logging in a distributed system

Tags: python, logging

We have several application servers (and different applications) running on Amazon AWS and our main method of logging is a combination of statsd, carbon/graphite, and an alert system based off of the metrics coming into carbon.  This has been working great for a lot of different situations but I feel we need something else to complement this type of logging.  Something that is not as much for streaming or visualization like graphite, but allows easy lookup by time/date, error type, etc...  What are some techniques that make reviewing your logs quick and effective?
My initial thought is to UDP all logging messages to a central server and insert them into a database (likely MongoDB).  Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: This problem has already been solved with logstash and elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. You could centralize logging to a central server and then have logstash consume the logs and store everything in elastic search. Then, you can use Kibana to search / lookup, etc. It's a good complement to statsD+graphite.

http://logstash.net

http://www.elasticsearch.org

http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/

Comment: Ribald, I'm in the middle of setting this up now.  It looks super promising, thanks for the tip!